# Add event listner on the click of the facebook and google+ icons generated through addthis.

Tags: addthis

I want to add a custom code which will tigger when the user click on the facebook and the google plus link.

We have added

```
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.open', eventHandler);
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.close', eventHandler);
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.share', eventHandler);
```

But non of them is fireing on the click of these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting nothing and then figured that the `addEventListener` was probably firing before the object was in place, so I wrapped it in a `$(document).ready()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Alert a message when the user shares somewhere
    function shareEventHandler(evt) { 
        //console.log(evt); // look in the browser for the object details
        alert(evt.data.service);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.share', shareEventHandler);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This does not seem to help. Of the elements listed at http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1365497-addthis-javascript-events I can only get 'addthis.ready' to fire. Not even adding the other events upon the ready event makes any difference.